# fn keys reversed (windows 10,toshiba laptop)

Tags: windows-10, toshiba-laptop, fn-key

Everytime I want to change music, change the volume, adjust the brightness, etc.. I need to press the fn button
back then I don't need to..

I tried everything from installing the function key driver thing, going to my BIOS, looking for my HWsetup (which i don't have)

Comment: Do you have a model number? There are different ways of doing the same thing from computer to computer. As a guess, is there a key that says `fn Lock` or similar?